# Python + VS Code: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ' ' occur

Tags: automated-testing, python, mac, vscode

Facing issue with error :

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

Basically, Error is not specific to module 'selenium'. Facing this issue in VS Code even when, I have selenium installed for python 2.x and 3.x

Refer below image:

[image]

I have tried :

```
pip install selenium
```

OR

```
pip3 install selenium
```

Please suggest if anyone has working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following solution worked for me:

- Cross **check you have installed the modul**e for which error occurred
- You can check it using cmd `pip3 show selenium` i.e. `pip3 show <module_name>`
- Expectations are to **get details about respective module**
- If not then try `pip install selenium` or `pip3 install selenium`
- Open **VS Code > Preferences > settings**
- Enter "**python default interpreter path**" in searchbox

[image]

- Enter appropriate version **python** or **python3** for your project